# kvm modules for kernel 4.8.0-rc2+

Tags: kernel, debian, kvm

I'm trying to create a virtual machine with virt-manager, but getting an error

> Warning: KVM modules is not available.

The modules are not loaded by default, but when I load them manually with modprobe, lsmod output confirms that they are loaded, but error is not disappeared.

How can I find required modules for 4.8.0-rc2+ kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Check your CPU with (intel and AMD):

```
egrep '(vmx|svm)' --color=always /proc/cpuinfo
```

If you don't have an output your CPU doesn't support the virtualization

install it :

```
sudo apt-get install kvm qemu
```

Load the module:

```
sudo modprobe kvm
```

If you get an error " error insering" enable the virtualization  in your BIOS settings.

If you have an Intel CPU you can load the module with

```
sudo modprobe kvm-intel
```

AMD:

```
sudo modprobe kvm-amd
```

To load the module permanantly edit your `/etc/modules` and add the following two lines

```
kvm
kvm-intel
```

or

```
kvm
kvm-amd
```